# How do I make my product show up in Windows 10's "Apps & features" list?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, windows-10

I have a windows desktop product that installs through a MSI, but when I install it on Windows 10 it isn't listed under the "Apps & features" settings. Anybody know where that list looks to populate its contents?

For reference, this is the list I'm talking about - http://microsoft-news.com/windows-10-now-allows-users-to-manage-win32-apps/

**Answer:** make sure the "UninstallString" registry entry for your product exists

```
[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentControlSet\Uninstall\<guid>]
"UninstallString"="msiexec /x <ProductCode>"
```

Answer (score 0):

My MSI's (both per machine and per user) are showing up there.  Are you seeing it in the control panel view?

I don't know of any doco on this topic yet.

I do know that I've seen this new screen break uninstalls.  See:

http://blog.iswix.com/2015/08/dtf-bug-with-new-windows-10-apps-and.html

Comment: My installer does show up in the Control Panel (ARP), but it isn't showing in the new Windows 10 "Apps & Features" settings dialog. Wondering what information/registries that list pulls from...

Comment: One way to find out... it would make sense.  Theory: The new ARP doesn't have a change button so from it's perspective it can't be removed therefore don't show it.